# AngularJS is not registering module in IE 11

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `angularJS 1.5.1` and when i try to run my application on IE 11 i got the following error :

> [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error:
> [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either
> misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a
> module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
> argument.
>
> errors.angularjs.org/1.5.1/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp    at Anonymous
> function (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:2034:11)    at ensure
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:1958:5)    at module
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:2032:7)    at Anonymous function
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:4524:11)    at forEach
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:321:11)    at loadModules
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:4508:5)    at createInjector
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:4430:3)    at doBootstrap
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:1710:5)    at bootstrap
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:1731:5)    at angularInit
> (code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.js:1616:5)

My index.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org"  id="ng-app">
<!-- Added here the app angular -->

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

I don't know how to fix this issue, my app works with browsers `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

**EDITED:**

This is the declaration of my app:

```
var myApp = angular.module(
    'myApp', 
    [ 
        'restangular', 
        'ui.router',  
        'ngMessages', 
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'angularSoap',
        'ngTagsInput', 
        'myApp.controllers', 
        'myApp.services' , 
        'myApp.filters','datatables'
    ]
);
```

The following modules are predefined:

```
'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services' , 'myApp.filters'
```

How can I know which functions are not compatible with IE?

Comment: Might be using methods in your code that aren't supported by IE. Then angular is catching the error

Comment: As per your code you seem to forgot to include the AngularJS library in index.html file. This shouldn't work in either of the browsers. Post your complete code to get the quick solution.

Comment: Can you show your `angular.module(...)` dependancies as well as what  `<script>` you have?

Comment: i edited my question

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209309/angularjs-and-ie-8-errors-on-services