# AngularJS and IE 8 errors on services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to deploy my AngularJS 1.5.1 on IE version 8 or Higher.

The app was crached in the first attempt and i got many errors for all my js services all with the error:

> SCRIPT1003: ':' attendu

example :

```
var servcModule = angular.module('myApp.services',[]);

servcModule.factory('NameService', function(Restangular,$http) {

            var list=null;


            var getList = function(Key){

                var result = $http({
                    method: 'POST', url:'NameService/getList',
                    data: Key
                }).then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
                return result;

            }


            var getListPersone = function(){
                var listPersone = Restangular.all('NameService/getListPersone');
                return listPersone.getList().$object;
            }


    return {
        getList, // here the error
        getListPersone
        };
    } );
```

The error pointed in line "getList," after "return {", and also for the other the same error in the line just after "return {"

Comment: Who still supports IE8 in 2018 -_-' Drop it already

Comment: You can't use that object shortcut in IE8.  Use `return {getList:getList, getListPersone:getListPersone}`.

Comment: even with Edge the same issue...

Comment: ok zero298, i will change them all with your suggestion

Comment: See this compatability table: [Object initializer Shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: Angular dropped IE8 support in v1.3. You need to downgrade if you intend to support it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 (And IE/Edge in general) certainly doesn't support this ES6 syntactic sugar :

```
return {
        getList, // here the error
        getListPersone
};
```

Use good old ES5 :

```
return {
        getList : getList,
        getListPersone :getListPersone
};
```

Comment: Also angular dropped IE8 support in version 1.3 https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: I know, but for some reason, apparently some people still use it, so some developers still (try to) support it

Comment: I'm not saying they can't support it but if they do they need to use v1.2. Just added comment for clarity